# What is leaf_values from Python LightGBM?

Tags: python, lightgbm

I'm using the LightGBM Package.

I have successfully created a new tree using "create_tree_digraph" but I face some trouble understanding the result.

There is "leaf_value" in a leaf node. I don't know what it means. Please, somebody help me understand this. Thanks. :)

I used this example code from here: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/06/which-algorithm-takes-the-crown-light-gbm-vs-xgboost/

```
#importing standard libraries 
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import Series, DataFrame 
import graphviz

import lightgbm as lgb 

#loading our training dataset 'adult.csv' with name 'data' using pandas 
data=pd.read_csv('./adult.csv',header=None) 

#Assigning names to the columns 
data.columns=['age','workclass','fnlwgt','education','education-num','marital_Status','occupation','relationship','race','sex','capital_gain','capital_loss','hours_per_week','native_country','Income'] 

# Label Encoding our target variable 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder
l=LabelEncoder()
l.fit(data.Income) 

data.Income=Series(l.transform(data.Income))  #label encoding our target variable  

#One Hot Encoding of the Categorical features 
one_hot_workclass=pd.get_dummies(data.workclass) 
one_hot_education=pd.get_dummies(data.education) 

#removing categorical features 
data.drop(['workclass','education','marital_Status','occupation','relationship','race','sex','native_country'],axis=1,inplace=True)  

#Merging one hot encoded features with our dataset 'data' 
data=pd.concat([data,one_hot_workclass,one_hot_education],axis=1) 

#Here our target variable is 'Income' with values as 1 or 0.  
#Separating our data into features dataset x and our target dataset y 
x=data.drop('Income',axis=1) 
y=data.Income 

#Imputing missing values in our target variable 
y.fillna(y.mode()[0],inplace=True) 

#Now splitting our dataset into test and train 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=.3)

train_data=lgb.Dataset(x_train,label=y_train)

#setting parameters for lightgbm
param = {'num_leaves':150, 'objective':'binary','max_depth':3,'learning_rate':.05,'max_bin':200}
param['metric'] = ['auc', 'binary_logloss']

#training our model using light gbm
num_round=50
lgbm=lgb.train(param,train_data,num_round)

graph = lgb.create_tree_digraph(lgbm)
graph.render(view=True)
```

Then I applied 'create_tree_digraph' function.

[Pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCT1d.png)

Comment: Please add your code here!

Comment: I added my code! sorry.

Comment: @YoonSangpill I believe, you have already got the answer asking directly in lighgbm github issues :)

Comment: Oh Yes. I'm Sorry and Thanks

Answer (score 2):

These are the raw predicted probabilities before the sigmoid function is applied. However, one thing to be aware of is your image is only showing 1 tree out of the entire model so it will not be the same as the actual outcome (unless your model is just this 1 tree).

This [Image](https://annalyzin.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/decision-trees-titanic-tutorial.png) is showing what it would look like if you applied the sigmoid to the leaf values prior to creating the plots.

Comment: Thanks. Then what should I do if I want to see the tree to the entire model?

Comment: @YoonSangpill Your final model is a combination of all trees so there is not really an efficient way to visualize them all. If your model was created with 1000 trees, you would need to look at all 1000 trees seperatly to see the 'final' model.

If you're looking for like feature importance or just more insight on what's going on, I recommend using [SHAP](https://github.com/slundberg/shap). Take a look at the force plots and dependence plots to see how features effect the model.